# NullPointerException throw while using gdata docs java library upon attempting a file upload

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, google-api, gdata-api

Basically I'm getting this error...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null response body
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException.setResponse(ServiceException.java:222)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:572)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)
```

I'm using the `gdocs-3.0` library and it all appears to work at runtime, except it fails when executing an upload of a file. I'm using the OAuth2 credentials system, is it possible this is the cause of the problem? Is it because I'm uploading content like mp3s rather than docs?

Is there a better library to access the document list api or is this it?

Comment: please add your code so that we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Please show us the code where this error is occurring. Without your code, we will only be guessing the cause of the problem, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Also, you're suggesting that the problem may be because you're trying to upload mp3s. Therefore, have you tried to upload docs, and is it successful?

Comment: Yes I had uploaded an MP3 file and because docslist/drive are now kind of the same thing it worked through the web interface just not through the gdocs api

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason I was getting this was a case of my application not wanting to upload a large document and instead needing to use the resumable media upload.